# I'm prompting for a string, but I receive an out of bounds exception before the prompt can execute

Tags: java, exception

My main method for this program, which runs the readInput and writeOutput methods, is in a different java file. My question is as follows.

[Here is the pastebin of it](http://pastebin.com/zRGeQMU8)

Why is Java giving me an out of bounds exception at lines 31 and 32 before I can even enter a string? I'm trying to store the first character of the string as a char to use it in the following "if, else if, else" statement.

Any hints as to what might be the problem? I'm willing to bet it's something simple that I accidentally glossed right over while typing this up.

For those who cannot get the link to work, the code is as follows.

```
    System.out.println("Is the nature increase, decrease, or neutral?");
char nature;
nature = keys.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

if(nature=='i')
  natureMult=1.1;
else if(nature=='n')
  natureMult=1.0;
else if(nature=='d')
  natureMult=0.9;
else
{
  System.out.println("Error! You entered an invalid multiplier!");
  System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Your link does not work.  You need to show your code IN the question.  Go read this - http://sscce.org/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: It's posted now. I accidentally forgot to post the pastebin at first.

Comment: @JonC: No, he means put your code in the text of your question, not on some external site.

Answer (score 1):

[`Scanner#nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) does not consume newline characters

Instead they get pased through to the next `Scanner` method as is the case here. `nextInt` is not consuming the newline character before the `nextLine()` statement in (the) question so the `Scanner` instance `keys` is not blocking. Add a `nextLine()` statement before the statement to consume the character

```
keys.nextLine(); // add this 
nature = keys.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
```